# Google App Engine app.yaml doesn't work on legacy Python 2.5 Master/Slave applicaton

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app.yaml

Have a legacy GAE application running Python 2.5 and Master/Slave.

Trying to get url routing working, this is what I have in `app.yaml`:

```
application: theapp
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
    - url: /rest/.*
      script: np/resources/rest.py
```

Would like for this to work with urls like:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/something
```

But I keep getting a `404` error

According to the [app engine documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#About_app_yaml), this should work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us handler register code.

Comment: You mean the stuff at the top?

Comment: Nope, the python code that registers the handlers.

Comment: I"m not totally sure, but it sounds like what you are asking for is app-engine library code? I think this is located in "dev_appserver.py", but its a pretty big file.

Comment: Show the rest.py script.